# mysql query dsl grammar getting one value using key value

Tags: mysql, jpa, querydsl

I'm getting `fno` by `proNo` wrongly in sql query

Here is my query:

```
@Query(value = "select f.fno from files f where 
f.pro_no = proNo", nativeQuery = false)
Integer findFno(@Param("proNo") Long proNo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Named Parameters

```
@Query(value = "select f.fno from files f where f.pro_no = :proNo") 
Integer findFno(@Param("proNo") Long proNo);
```

or Positional Parameters,

```
@Query(value = "select f.fno from files f where f.pro_no = ?1") 
Integer findFno(Long proNo);
```